Issues with Distorted Images on Mobile and Desktop Using Konva.js and HTML5 Canvas in .NET Core
I'm experiencing significant image distortion issues when placing a logo on a canvas in my .NET Core project using Konva.js for canvas manipulation. The problem is more pronounced on mobile devices compared to desktop devices.
On Mobile Devices:
The logo image appears slightly distorted when initially placed on the canvas.
After saving the image, the distortion increases significantly, and the content is not displayed properly.
On Desktop Devices:
The logo image appears slightly distorted when initially placed on the canvas.
After saving the image, the content is visible but not as clear as it should be.
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var objectOrgin = "";
    var stepname = $('.step-name').val();
    var productId = $('.product-id').val();
    var position = $('.position').val();
    var searchUrl = stepname == "sponsorlogo" ? '/umbraco/surface/DYO/GetCoOrdinatesForSponsorLogoWithObjectOrgin' : '/umbraco/surface/DYO/GetCoOrdinatesForClubLogoWithObjectOrgin';
    $.ajax({
        url: searchUrl,
        method: 'GET',
        data: { productId: productId, position: position },
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null) {
                x = response.X;
                y = response.Y;
                objectOrgin = response.ObjectOrgin.toLowerCase();
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('Error:', error);
        }
    });

    var img = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-image")[0];
    img.src = item.Image;
    var ImgURL = localStorage.getItem('MyLogoImage');
    var ResizedImage = new Image();
    ResizedImage.src = ImgURL;

    ResizedImage.onload = function () {
        var width = 749;
        var height = 496;
        var max_width = 650;
        var max_height = 430;
        if (ResizedImage.width > ResizedImage.height) {
            if (ResizedImage.width > max_width) {
                ResizedImage.height = Math.round(ResizedImage.height * (max_width / ResizedImage.width));
                ResizedImage.width = max_width;
            }
        } else {
            if (ResizedImage.height > max_height) {
                ResizedImage.width = Math.round(ResizedImage.width * (max_height / ResizedImage.height));
                ResizedImage.height = max_height;
            }
        }

        var stage = new Konva.Stage({
            container: 'MyLogocontainer',
            width: width,
            height: height
        });

        var layer = new Konva.Layer();
        stage.add(layer);
        var value = 0.4776785714285714;
        var adultDimensions = null;
        var selectedIndex = $('.selected-index').val();

        if (selectedIndex == "" || selectedIndex == undefined || selectedIndex == "undefined") {
            adultDimensions = extractAdultSizeDimensions(item);
        }
        else {
            var index = parseInt(selectedIndex);
            adultDimensions = extractAdultSizeDimensions(clublogoData[index]);
        }

        var finalAdultHeight = adultDimensions.height * value;
        var finalAdultWidth = adultDimensions.width * value;
        var adjustedX = x * value;
        var adjustedY = y * value;

        switch (objectOrgin) {
            case 'top':
                adjustedX -= finalAdultWidth / 2;
                break;
            case 'bottom':
                adjustedX -= finalAdultWidth / 2;
                adjustedY -= finalAdultHeight;
                break;
            case 'left':
                adjustedY -= finalAdultHeight / 2;
                break;
            case 'right':
                adjustedX -= finalAdultWidth;
                adjustedY -= finalAdultHeight / 2;
                break;
            case 'center':
                adjustedX -= finalAdultWidth / 2;
                adjustedY -= finalAdultHeight / 2;
                break;
            default:
                adjustedX -= finalAdultWidth / 2;
                adjustedY -= finalAdultHeight / 2;
                break;
        }

        var darthVaderImg = new Konva.Image({
            image: ResizedImage,
            x: adjustedX,
            y: adjustedY,
            width: finalAdultWidth,
            height: finalAdultHeight
        });

        layer.add(darthVaderImg);
        layer.draw();

        function moveLogo(dx, dy) {
            var scale = stage.scaleX();
            adjustedX += dx * scale;
            adjustedY += dy * scale;
            darthVaderImg.setAttrs({
                x: adjustedX,
                y: adjustedY
            });
            layer.draw();
        }

        var rSaveButton = document.getElementById('rremoveallanchor');
        if (rSaveButton != undefined) {
            document.getElementById('rremoveallanchor').addEventListener('click', function () {
                saveResizedLogo();
            });
        }

        var rmoveUpBtn = document.getElementById('rmoveUpBtn');
        if (rmoveUpBtn) {
            document.getElementById('rmoveUpBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                moveLogo(0, -10);
            });
        }

        var rmoveDownBtn = document.getElementById('rmoveDownBtn');
        if (rmoveDownBtn) {
            document.getElementById('rmoveDownBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                moveLogo(0, 10);
            });
        }

        var rmoveLeftBtn = document.getElementById('rmoveLeftBtn');
        if (rmoveLeftBtn) {
            document.getElementById('rmoveLeftBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                moveLogo(-10, 0);
            });
        }

        var rmoveRightBtn = document.getElementById('rmoveRightBtn');
        if (rmoveRightBtn) {
            document.getElementById('rmoveRightBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                moveLogo(10, 0);
            });
        }

        function saveResizedLogo() {
            debugger
            var stage = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
            var NewLogoImage = stage[1].toDataURL();
            localStorage.setItem("MyResizedLogo", NewLogoImage);
        }


        var saveButton = document.getElementById('removeallanchor');
        if (saveButton != undefined) {
            document.getElementById('removeallanchor').addEventListener('click', function () {
                saveResizedLogo();
            });
        }

        var moveUpBtn = document.getElementById('moveUpBtn');
        if (moveUpBtn) {
            document.getElementById('moveUpBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                moveLogo(0, -10);
            });
        }

        var moveDownBtn = document.getElementById('moveDownBtn');
        if (moveDownBtn) {
            document.getElementById('moveDownBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                moveLogo(0, 10);
            });
        }

        var moveLeftBtn = document.getElementById('moveLeftBtn');
        if (moveLeftBtn) {
            document.getElementById('moveLeftBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                moveLogo(-10, 0);
            });
        }

        var moveRightBtn = document.getElementById('moveRightBtn');
        if (moveRightBtn) {
            document.getElementById('moveRightBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
                moveLogo(10, 0);
            });
        }

        function fitStageIntoParentContainer() {
            var container = document.querySelector('#CcanvasWrapper');
            var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
            var scale = containerWidth / width;
            stage.width(width * scale);
            stage.height(height * scale);
            stage.scale({ x: scale, y: scale });
            stage.draw();
        }
        fitStageIntoParentContainer();
        window.addEventListener('resize', fitStageIntoParentContainer);
    }
});
<div class="dyo_right">
     <div class="main_right_dyo right_creating_shirt">
         <div class="tshirt_sec">
             <img crossOrigin="Anonymous" id="canvasImg" src="@base64String" alt="" style="display:none" class="hidden-xs">
             <img crossOrigin="Anonymous" id="previousImgtest" alt="" style="display:none" class="hidden-xs" />
             <img crossOrigin="Anonymous" id="previousImg" alt="" style="display:none" class="hidden-xs" />

             <img id="numberImage" src="" alt="" style="display:none" class="hidden-xs" />
             <div id="CcanvasWrapper">
                 <canvas width="749" height="496" id="canvas1" style="z-index:1000;"></canvas>
                 <div id="MyLogocontainer" class="resize-img"></div>
             </div>
             <canvas id="canvas2" width="749" height="496" style="display:none"></canvas>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>

I have tried the above and all related suggestions, but none of them worked for me. I want the image to be added to the canvas in any size on any device and displayed perfectly after saving, meaning it should merge seamlessly into the canvas. Additionally, on desktop devices, the image should display perfectly, and when uploaded from any device, it should be shown perfectly on any other device.

Your HTML is invalid - it's </script>, not <script/>.

Saving a resized image increases distortion on every save. A solution is to keep an image with naturalWidth/Height in the memory, reflect changes made to viewed image to the image in the memory and save that image instead of the viewed image.

Welcome to SO.
The desire to have an uploaded image display perfectly on all devices (not quite what you said but seems to be what you mean) is not achievable without more work. Research what happens when images are scaled. You lose image information when reducing size and image information is added based on algorithmic selection of color for new pixels when you increase image size. Neither retain the original quality of the initial image. The only way to be perfect is to have pre-prepared images at all possible output size.
